# What is different between Container vs Grid container in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

As I mentioned in question: What is different between **Container** vs **Grid** has attribute `container` in Material-UI?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I visited the documentation of material UI, here's what I found while inspecting these:

## Container

When you use `<Container>` in your code, following styles will be applied to your `<Container>` component.

[image]

As you can see in above screenshot, there are two important properties present,

- `display: block`
- `max-width: 600px` (In the media queries, so it varies depending on the viewport width)

## Grid

When you use  in your code with attribute container, following styles will be applied,

[image]

As you can see above, it utilizes the flexbox layout for holding the columns, which can be useful for holding the flex-items (i.e. columns). Also it has its max-width set depending on the type of spacing you are specifying.

After inspecting these differences, in my opinion, `<Container>` are used for outer wrapper which holds the all the components in it, whereas the `<Grid container>` can be used to create column layout (12-columns), which is not really possible in case of `<Container>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @TruongHoang you are welcome